# conditional if statement not working

Tags: arrays, bash

I want to check all the characters of a user's input and check than none other than the last char are space chars. Here is what I have:

```
lastEle="${#charArr[@]}"
lastEle=$((lastEle - 1))
for f in "${charArr[@]}" ; do
    if [[ "$f" != "${charArr["$lastEle"]}" && "$f" == " " ]] ; then        #'if' 
        abort "1" "$LINENO"    "Strings cannot contain space characters and at least one was detected in the input string" "exit"        #funct call
    fi
done
```

1. Index number for the character array's last element is determined
2. for loop used to cycle thru each array element
3. if conditional used to determine whether or not element being checked is last element, and if not that character for $f element is NOT a space " " character
4. if condition for any element is not true then call function `abort` to exit script

The if conditional does not appear to be working as written since when I input a string that does contain at least one space char the script does not exit, and I am certain the `abort` function works fine. I am sure the problem is some slight oversight on my part but for the life of me I cannot see it. If someone doesn't mind weighing in to enlighten me I would appreciate it.

Comment: how do you get an `charArr[@]` variable? Is there any reason to use `"${#charArr[@]}"` instead of `charArr[@]`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That seems like overkill to me.

If you simply want to detect whether a user has entered a string that contains any spaces not at the end <sup>(a)</sup>, just use the `bash` substitution facility:

```
$ x="hello";        if [[ "${x/ [^ ]/}" != "$x" ]]; then echo bad; fi

$ x="hello ";       if [[ "${x/ [^ ]/}" != "$x" ]]; then echo bad; fi

$ x="hello there";  if [[ "${x/ [^ ]/}" != "$x" ]]; then echo bad; fi
bad

$ x="hello there "; if [[ "${x/ [^ ]/}" != "$x" ]]; then echo bad; fi
bad
```

The substitution will simply find the first sequence of `space` followed by `nonspace`, and remove it. The variable expansion `${x/ [^ ]/}` means:

- take the variable `$x`.
- find the first occurrence of `" [^ ]"` (space followed by non-space).
- replace that with the empty string (i.e., remove it).

If it *does* remove it, the string will be different from the original and hence the `if` statement will "activate".

---

In terms of why what you have isn't working, it depends entirely on what `charArr` actually is. If it's a string along the lines of:

```
charArr="hello pax"
```

or:

```
read charArr
```

then putting `set -x` at the top of your script will show you *exactly* what the problem is:

```
+ charArr='hello pax'
+ lastEle=1
+ lastEle=0
+ for f in '"${charArr[@]}"'
+ [[ hello pax != \h\e\l\l\o\ \p\a\x ]]
```

In other words, it's *not* a character array but an array of *one* string.

Actually using a real character array:

```
charArr[0]="h"
charArr[1]="e"
charArr[2]="l"
charArr[3]="l"
charArr[4]="o"
charArr[5]=" "
charArr[6]="p"
charArr[7]="a"
charArr[8]="x"
```

will result in output that appears to work (notwithstanding the fact I have no `abort` function/program in my environment):

```
+ charArr[0]=h
+ charArr[1]=e
+ charArr[2]=l
+ charArr[3]=l
+ charArr[4]=o
+ charArr[5]=' '
+ charArr[6]=p
+ charArr[7]=a
+ charArr[8]=x
+ lastEle=9
+ lastEle=8
+ for f in '"${charArr[@]}"'
+ [[ h != \x ]]
+ [[ h == \  ]]
+ for f in '"${charArr[@]}"'
+ [[ e != \x ]]
+ [[ e == \  ]]
+ for f in '"${charArr[@]}"'
+ [[ l != \x ]]
+ [[ l == \  ]]
+ for f in '"${charArr[@]}"'
+ [[ l != \x ]]
+ [[ l == \  ]]
+ for f in '"${charArr[@]}"'
+ [[ o != \x ]]
+ [[ o == \  ]]
+ for f in '"${charArr[@]}"'
+ [[   != \x ]]
+ [[   == \  ]]
+ abort 1 16 'Strings cannot contain space characters and at least one was detected in the input string' exit
testprog.sh: line 16: abort: command not found
+ for f in '"${charArr[@]}"'
+ [[ p != \x ]]
+ [[ p == \  ]]
+ for f in '"${charArr[@]}"'
+ [[ a != \x ]]
+ [[ a == \  ]]
+ for f in '"${charArr[@]}"'
+ [[ x != \x ]]
```

In any case, I think the logic for detecting end of string was faulty from the get-go. If the characters were `agbc efg`, then it would actually stop at the *second* character since your check was simply "is this character equal to the last one in the array?". Hence you would never find that space after the `c`.

---

<sup>(a)</sup> Note that definition well, it includes as valid strings those that have *multiple* spaces at the end, such as `"hello<space><space>"`.

If you *don't* want that, you can opt for the following test instead:

```
if [[ ! $x =~ ^[^\ ]*\ ?$ ]]; then echo bad; fi
```

That basically checks to ensure that the *entire* variable (using `^` and `$` anchors) is composed of zero or more non-spaces (`[^\ ]*`) followed by an optional space (`\ ?`).

Comment: I had a feeling it was overkill, but to be honest I have never used the `bash` substitution facility. It works like a hot-damn, so now it's off to read up about it.

Comment: @scriptz, `man bash` is your friend, either in a shell or in your browser search bar.

Comment: but in all honesty I would still like to know why the `if` conditional fails when it should result in TRUE result

Comment: @scriptz, your wish is my command. See the update for analysis as to why it didn't work.

Comment: This will also validate multiple trailing spaces: `x='hello  '`. You shouldn't use substitutions for that. There are two sane options: the first one is to use globs: `[[ $x != *([^ ])?( ) ]]`. This seems much more natural than your hacky substitution. The second option is to use a regex: `[[ ! $x =~ ^[^\ ]*\ ?$ ]]`.

Comment: @gniourf_gniourf, multiple trailing spaces being valid was implicit in my answer: `a string that contains any spaces not at the end`. However, question could be read the other way so I'll incorporate that into the answer as suggested.

Answer (score 1):

How about this one? You have to modify the code a bit.

```
        input="Test string "
        if [[ `echo $input | sed 's/ *$//g' | grep -o " " | wc -l` > 0 ]]
        then
                echo "Strings cannot contain space characters and at least one was detected in the input string"
        else
                echo "Good string"
        fi
```